# How to access all of an Apache Spark's session streaming query custom listeners

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I was tes/ting creating custom streaming query listeners and attached them to my spark session on databricks. For example /

```
// my custom listener
val batchListener = new batchTimeListener()
 spark.streams.addListener(batchListener)
```

I was using a databricks notebook to test. I created quite a bit of custom listeners and registered them, before realizing they were/weren't working. I deleted the code for those previous listeners and don't recall what they were called. My query now has a ton of listeners, I see the messages I was printing.

I know how to remove the listener:

```
// remove listener
spark.streams.removeListener(batchListener)
```

Except I don't know the names of the many custom listeners. Is there a way to access all of the streaming query listeners that have been made? I would like to remove them from my spark session.

---

**Update  9/12/19**:
This is not available now but it will be in the future :

https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/25518

Comment: This is now available for the ones who may need it. You can acces it using `spark.streams.listListeners`